# Taylor expansion of a variable with small displacement

Tags: taylor-expansion

I got a question concerning the Taylor expansion of a function 
$ F(\vec{x},t+\Delta t)$, 
 where $\Delta t$ is a small displacement with $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$. 
 
In one of my books it is stated that the expansion looks like
$$ F(\vec{x},t+\Delta t) \approx F(\vec{x},t)+\Delta t\frac{\partial F(\vec{x},t)}{\partial t} $$

But I can't really get my head around on how to get there with a formal approach. 
Can anybody give me a hint or explanation?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* For every fixed $x$, the map $g(t) = F(x,t)$ is a function of one variable such that $g'(t) = \partial F/\partial t(x,t)$. What is the Taylor expansion of $g$?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $t + \Delta t = \epsilon$, hence $\epsilon$ evaluated in zero is $\epsilon_0 = t + \Delta t$ as $\Delta t \to 0$ hence $\epsilon_0 = t$.

Given this, you have the usual Taylor expansion:

$$F(x, \epsilon) \approx F(x, \epsilon_0) + F'(x, \epsilon_0)(\epsilon - \epsilon_0)$$

And because of what we said above this reads

$$F(x, t + \Delta t) \approx F(x, t) + F'(x, t)(t + \Delta t - t)$$

Eventually

$$F(x, t + \Delta t) \approx F(x, t) + \Delta t \frac{\partial F(x, t)}{\partial t}$$

Comment: Why can you use $ \frac{\partial F}{\partial \epsilon}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial(t+\Delta t)} \approx \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} $ so easily? Isn't it that you don't let $ \Delta t \rightarrow 0 $ for $ \epsilon $ in that case?

Comment: @P-A That reasoning is mathematically inconsistent, it's wrong to make that assumption because $\Delta t \to 0$ but it's not really zero

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor polynomial centered at $t_0$

$F(x,t) = F(x,t_0) + \frac {\partial F}{\partial t}(x,t_0) (t-t_0) + \epsilon$

and $\epsilon < M(t-t_0)^2$

$M$ is bounded. (Proof is left to the reader)

If $(t-t_0)$ is "small" then $(t-t_0)^2$ is "very small",  and $\epsilon$ is also "very small."

Now we replace $(t-t_0)$ with $\Delta t$

Answer (score 0):

Start with the ordinary definition of the Taylor series in the vicinity of $t=\tau$
$$
F(\vec{x},t) \approx F(\vec{x},\tau) + (t-\tau)\dot{F}(\vec{x}, \tau),
$$
which is an expression for $F(\vec{x}, t)$ that is accurate near to $t=\tau$.

If we now want an expression at $t = \tau + \delta_{\tau}$ where $\delta_{\tau}$ is small, we can use the Taylor series that we just derived by substituting $t = \tau + \delta_{\tau}$ which gives
$$
F(\vec{x},t=\tau+\delta_{\tau}) \approx F(\vec{x},\tau) + \delta_{\tau}\dot{F}(\vec{x}, \tau)
$$

Provided $\delta_{\tau}$ is small, $\tau + \delta_{\tau}$ should be "in the vicinity" of $\tau$, so using the original Taylor series is acceptable. The number of terms required will depend on the application and how "small" your $\delta_{\tau}$ is.